# How can I solve the delay from firebase database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

So here is my function code:

```
function Detail() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Grab the movie info from db
    db.collection("movies")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          // save the movie to the state
          setMovie(doc.data());
        } else {
          // redirect to home page
          console.log("no such document in firebase ");
        }
      });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Background>
        <img alt=" background" src={movie.backgroundImg} />
      </Background>
      <ImageTitle>
        <img alt="title" src={movie.titleImg} />
      </ImageTitle>

      <SubTitle>{movie.subtitle}</SubTitle>
      <Description>{movie.description}</Description>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Everything should be good here, but when I run the app, I get **TypeError: cannot read property 'backgroundImg' of undefined**

After spending a good few hours debugging and researching, I found out that the issue is, the function looking for the data before it had time to get it from the database.

What is the solution here? I know about the async function but never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UseEffect is executed after render and when value id value changes**

#### Note=> you need to render only if movie exists

```
function Detail() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Grab the movie info from db
    const unsubscribe=db.collection("movies")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          // save the movie to the state
          setMovie(doc.data());
        } else {
          // redirect to home page
          console.log("no such document in firebase ");
        }
      });
      return ()=>{
      //clean up function to unsubscribe to firestore changes
      unsubscribe();
    }
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <Container>
    //render only if movie exists
    {
    movie ? <div>
        <Background>
            <img alt=" background" src={movie.backgroundImg} />
          </Background>
          <ImageTitle>
            <img alt="title" src={movie.titleImg} />
          </ImageTitle>

          <SubTitle>{movie.subtitle}</SubTitle>
          <Description>{movie.description}</Description>
          </div>
      : <p>...loading</p>
    }
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional rendering in react and render different component based on `movie`

```
return (
    <Container>
{movie?
<React.Fragment>
      <Background>
        <img alt=" background" src={movie.backgroundImg} />
      </Background>
      <ImageTitle>
        <img alt="title" src={movie.titleImg} />
      </ImageTitle>

      <SubTitle>{movie.subtitle}</SubTitle>
      <Description>{movie.description}</Description>
</React.Fragment>
: <p>loading from firebase</p>}
    </Container>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want some loading state that controls wether the content is available or not, this is the refactored code:

***ps: If it doesn't work, check your logs so we can see the error***

```
function Detail() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    async function getMovie(id) {
      try {
        const doc = await db.collection("movies")
          .doc(id)
          .get()

        if (doc.exists()) {
          setMovie(doc)
        }
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

    getMovie(id)

    setLoading(false)
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      {!loading && (
        <>
          <Background>
            <img alt=" background" src={movie.backgroundImg} />
          </Background>
          <ImageTitle>
            <img alt="title" src={movie.titleImg} />
          </ImageTitle>

          <SubTitle>{movie.subtitle}</SubTitle>
          <Description>{movie.description}</Description>
        </>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React never assume that a request will be processed and the information will exist or React would render before the request is finished being processed. So you always want to use a `&&` operator

```
function Detail() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Grab the movie info from db
    db.collection("movies")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          // save the movie to the state
          setMovie(doc.data());
        } else {
          // redirect to home page
          console.log("no such document in firebase ");
        }
      });
  }, [id]);

  return (
    {movie &&
    <Container>
      <Background>
        <img alt=" background" src={movie.backgroundImg} />
      </Background>
      <ImageTitle>
        <img alt="title" src={movie.titleImg} />
      </ImageTitle>

      <SubTitle>{movie.subtitle}</SubTitle>
      <Description>{movie.description}</Description>
    </Container>}
  );
}
```